# APSHook.dll keylogger record keyboard inputs

Tags: keyloggers

My antivirus software detected APSHook.dll which is an application used by credible companies ( Cognizance Identity Manager or Bioscrypt VeriSoft Single Sign On or Credential Manager for HP ProtectTools or ASUS Security Protect Manager by Bioscrypt (l1id.com) or Cognizance (www.cognizancesecurity.com)). http://www.file.net/process/apshook.dll.html

**APSHook.dll is able to record keyboard and mouse inputs and monitor applications. **
It has a AppInit_DLLs registry value.

It's a keylogger I wasn't aware of! How do I find all the keyboard inputs it recorded and delete them?